# How to identify checkboxes of a specific column in a grid using javascript

Tags: javascript

i already posted this question.Sorry that i failed to add any code.That thread is closed. Apologies. I'm bothering you all again.

Anyways, i just want to identify checkboxes of a specific columns in a radgrid? i have two columns. and two buttons.if i click one button i need to check/uncheck checkboxes of that particular column alone.Kind help please?i already tried this. Now all checkboxes in the grid are getting checked/unchecked.

Please find the code below.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); //or document.forms[0].elements;

   for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) 
   {
       if (input[i].type == "checkbox") 
       {
           if (input[i].checked) {
               input[i].checked = false;
           }
           else 
           {
               input[i].checked = true;
           }
       }
   }
```

Please tell me on how can i pick check boxes of a particular column alone?

HTML Code:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head id="Head1" runat="server">
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


       function clickbutton()
        {
           debugger;

           var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); //or document.forms[0].elements;

           for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) 
           {
               if (input[i].type == "checkbox") 
               {
                   if (input[i].checked) {
                       input[i].checked = false;
                   }
                   else 
                   {
                       input[i].checked = true;
                   }
               }
           }   



       }


</script>
</head>
<body class="BODY">
    <form id="mainForm" method="post" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

        <!-- content start -->
        <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
            <AjaxSettings>
                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid1">
                    <UpdatedControls>
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" />
                    </UpdatedControls>
                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="clrFilters">
                    <UpdatedControls>
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" />
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="clrFilters" />
                    </UpdatedControls>
                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            </AjaxSettings>
        </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            AllowSorting="True" ClientSettings-Scrolling-AllowScroll="true"
            AllowFilteringByColumn="True" Width="1251px" runat="server" OnColumnCreating="RadGrid1_ColumnCreating"  
            OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand" 
            OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" Skin="Gray"
             OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound"  OnItemCreated="RadGrid1_ItemCreated"
           >
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <AlternatingItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages" />
            <MasterTableView>


<RowIndicatorColumn>
<HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
</RowIndicatorColumn>

<ExpandCollapseColumn>
<HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
</ExpandCollapseColumn>
            </MasterTableView>


            <SelectedItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />


<ClientSettings>
    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
<Scrolling AllowScroll="True"></Scrolling>
</ClientSettings>

<FilterMenu EnableTheming="True">
<CollapseAnimation Type="OutQuint" Duration="200"></CollapseAnimation>
</FilterMenu>

            <EditItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <ActiveItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <FilterItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />

        </telerik:RadGrid>


        <br />



        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <p>



        </p>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I m creating Checkboxes and Button dynamically.

Comment: Can you show us your Grid/HTML?

Comment: Are the names of the `<input`> elements unique to the row/column? Might be able to check the name or a class of the input field to determine if it's the column you'd like.

Comment: We need to see the HTML to help you. You should use jQuery or Prototype to perform this kind of task. With jQuery you can do this in a single line of code. I also suggest you to use distinct css class names for cells on each column so it's much easier to select all checkboxes for a particupar column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think like these are more easely done using JQuery.

But nevertheless... if the `input` tags are really alternating each other, then you can pseudo-select them using a modulo operation.

Made an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gnRQj/

Answer (score 0):

```
document.forms[ 0 ].addEventListener( 'click', function( e ) {
    if ( e.target.nodeName === 'input' ) {
        // This gets the index of the parent (supposedly the TD)
        // inside the parent of the parent (supposedly the TR).
        var i = [].indexOf.call( e.target.parentNode.parentNode,
            e.target.parentNode );

        // So uncheck all the checkboxes of this column.
        // Sending to another function is better or the code
        // becomes cluttered.
        uncheckColumn( i );
    }
};

function uncheckColumn( index ) {
    // For each TD
    [].forEach.call( document.getElementById( 'tr-id' ).children[ index ],
        function( column ) {
        column.firstElementChild.checked = column.firstElementChild.checked
            ? false : true;
    } );
}
```

This requires modern browsers however. For legacy browsers support, take a look at jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set yourself up a plan for finding the checkboxes again after they are created.  You could do this a variety of ways, but one way is to assign name attributes to your checkboxes based on the column they are in and use document.getElementsByName() (instead of tagname).

You may also want to look into using CSS classes to identify your elements.  I personally use jQuery quite a bit and with jQuery it is easy to find a group of elements by class.

$('.classname')  is an example of using a jQuery selector to find elements that have a class of 'classname';

Good luck and have fun.